# Multiple FQL queries in one

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

In my project I'm using `FacebookSDK`, I need to get friends list with pagination, so how can I get friends count and friends list (offset "value", limit 10) in one `FQL query`?

my queries are:

```
SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid = me()
SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode your two queries as a JSON object and pass that object as the query to the `/fql` endpoint:

```
{
  'num_friends':'SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid = me()',
  'ten_friends':'SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0'
}
```

For specific information on using multiqueries with the iOS SDK, see step 2b of [this tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/run-fql-queries-ios-sdk/)